# extract name from mulitple levels multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array. It can be extented upto N- levels. I want to collect only name. Name from child to Parent. For example I need output like this

> name => "Sport/Algemeen/techn.sp.ondgd/ondergoed dames/Sport bh"

. Level can be increated upto N numbers.

```
   [categories] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [@id] => 1
                        [name] => 78057 | Sport bh
                        [parent] => Array
                            (
                                [@id] => 2
                                [name] => 7805 | ondergoed dames
                                [parent] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@id] => 3
                                        [name] => 780 | techn.sp.ondgd
                                        [parent] => Array
                                            (
                                                [@id] => 4
                                                [name] => Algemeen
                                                [parent] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [@id] => 5
                                                        [name] => Sport
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: See i can extract data using foreach loop. But i cant predict levels. There must be some easiest way to accomplish this. So if someone helps me that would be really appreciate.

Comment: @Palanikumar at least you have to go trough `foreach`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrPush = array();
function iterator($arr){
    global $arrPush;
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        if(is_array($val))
            iterator($val);
        if($key == "name"){
            $str = explode("|", $val);
            $arrPush[] =  isset($str[1])?$str[1]:$str[0];
        }
        //filter the $key and $val here and do what you want
    }
}
iterator($sweet);
$str = implode("/", array_reverse($arrPush));
echo $str;
```

Sport/Algemeen/ techn.sp.ondgd/ ondergoed dames/ Sport bh

Answer (score 1):

Like that (haven't tested)

```
function namify($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $cat) {
        if(!empty($cat['parent']) && is_array($cat['parent'])) {
            return $cat['name'].namify($cat['parent']);
        } else {
            return $cat['name'];
        }
    }
}

echo namify($categories);
```